# Finding minimum value for signed integers

Tags: assembly, arm, arm7

In ARM7 assembly I want to find the smaller of the two numbers. The numbers are to be signed 32 bit values. Here is what I have tried -

```
.global min32
.text
 min: 
     CMP R0,R1
     BGE end
     BX LR
 end:
 MOV R0, R1
 BX LR
```

What should I change in this?

Comment: Why not just `cmp r0, r1` and then `movgt r0, r1` to move `r1` to `r0` if `r0` is greater than `r1`. No need to jump. Just use the condition suffix `GT` to `mov` to only preform the `mov` if `r0` is greater than `r1`.  See  [ARM Condition code suffixes](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289860997.htm) (this presumes you want as signed-comparison, use `HI` for unsigned higher otherwise)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is my code incorrect though?

Comment: No, not at all, your code looks fine, You don't use any registers that need to be preserved (`r4` and above), and you should also look into a function *prologue* and *epilogue* when you do or when you want to create space for local variables. I found [10.3 Stack Management In a Function](https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-stack-manage.html) a good reference (the whole tutorial is a good introduction) The instruction saving condition codes, etc.. are just refinements, but your base logic was fine. Good luck with your assembly programming. Pay close attention to the details `:)`